# AS3: Is there a limit to the number of SharedObjects?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a limit to the NUMBER of SharedObject files a single application can store by default?  Is there an overall size limit?  All I can find information on is the size limit of an individual file, which defaults to 100kb.

I apologize if this has been asked, I just can't find it!

Comment: You could knock up a test pretty quickly I reckon.

Comment: Certainly, but my settings may not be the default, and for that matter the default may vary from Operating System to Operating System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the overall size is only limited by the user's file system for the location of shared data storage, say if the user's Windows's `C:` drive is only 40GB, and software plus OS takes 35GB, there's only 5GB space left to store various "temporary" files including shared object data. The number of SOs is not limited by Flash/browser engine.

The size limit is not of "individual file" as this can too get pretty high, but for the **site** where your SWF is located, and is shared among all of the SWFs from that site. This indeed defaults to 100kb per site, and this is harsh, but is remediable by telling the user to allow this site to store more.

Comment: Wow, that is harsh!  That's rather disappointing to learn.  I was really looking forward to the possibility of using 1MB+ of SOs all to myself, but it is for a flash game that will be hosted on Kongregate!

Comment: Thankfully Kongregate is already aware of this, and indeed the 100kb limitation is for ALL of the Kongregate's games total. I've just checked that exactly for Kongregate (the text was "How much data you want `chat.kongregate.com` to store?", localized), and there is at least Arkandian Crusade that stores 1M+ for each of its saves (autosave included), so I guess Kongregate users have already allowed at least 10M for the site, if not unlimited. :D Don't worry about game portals, but do notify the player about needing this much storage.

Comment: Alright, thanks a ton for the information, you have been extremely helpful!